# spring data JDBC generates invalid queries

Tags: one-to-many, spring-data-jdbc

[image: table structure]

Here is my table structure. I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` 3.0.3. I mapped these tables like below.

```java
@Table("ticket")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    private TicketType ticketType;

// getters and setters
}

@Table("ticket_type")
public class TicketType {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

// getters and setters

}
```

when I try to retrieve tickets, spring throws a BadSqlGrammarException. The generated query is

```sql
SELECT `ticket`.`id` AS `id`, `ticket`.`subject` AS `subject`, `ticketType`.`id` AS `tickettype_id`, `ticketType`.`name` AS `tickettype_name` FROM `ticket` LEFT OUTER JOIN `ticket_type` `ticketType` ON `ticketType`.`ticket` = `ticket`.`id`
```

why spring data JDBC generates the on cause as

```sql
`ticketType`.`ticket` = `ticket`.`id`
```

instead of

```sql
`ticketType`.`id` = `ticket`.`ticket_type`
```

I tried @MappedCollection(idColumn = "ticket_id") to the ticketType field in Ticket class. then the on cause of generated query was `ticketType`.`ticket_id` = `ticket`.`id`. what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data JDBC expects for one-to-one relationships that the foreign key goes in the same direction as it would for a one-to-many relationship.

While this might seem weird at first, I do think it makes a lot of sense.
It is symmetric to the one-to-many case.
The aggregate root (`Ticket`) should not depend on the referenced entity (`TicketType`) and therefore it also shouldn't have the reference in the table, which then would have to be nullable.
With the the foreign key pointing from the referenced entity to the aggregate root it can be `not null`.

See also [*Allow for FK in normal direction [DATAJDBC-128]*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/360)

That said, from the entity names it seems you don't want to create a one-to-one but a one-to-many relationship.
Those get modelled as a simple id value, optionally wrapped in an `AggregateReference` in Spring Data JDBC.
See [*Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates*](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the ManyToOne and joinColumn annotation to map the entity while still keeping the FK column field.

```
    @Table("ticket")
public class Ticket {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String subject;
    @Column(name = "ticket_type")
    private int ticketType;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_type", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private TicketType ticketType;

// getters and setters
}
```

Comment: ManyToOne & JoinColumn Annotations are for JPA right ? , This is Spring data JDBC not Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i think you can use @MappedCollection inside entity TicketType, that means Set<Ticket> tickets